# Is Warrior Kings on Steam/GOG.com the "Remastered Edition"?

Tags: steam, version-differences, gog

No official info on Steam and GOG.com, that's why I'm asking. [About "Remastered Edition"](http://www.gog.com/forum/general_archive/warrior_kings_remastered/post5).